# Trouble connecting to BigQuery using Google Cloud Client Library in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'm trying to connect to Google BigQuery using the Google Cloud Client Library. I have a service account JSON credentials file located at src/main/resources/my-todo/vm-dev-393108-80d765f9af09.json in my project.

I've defined the path to my credentials in application.properties like so:

myapp.google.credentials.path=classpath:vm-dev-393108-80d765f9af09.json

And I use this path to load the credentials in my Spring configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class BigQueryConfig {
@Value("${myapp.google.credentials.path}")
private String googleCredentialsPath;

    @Bean
    public GoogleCredentials googleCredentials() {
        try (FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(googleCredentialsPath)) {
            return GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load BigQuery credentials", e);
        }
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BigQuery bigQuery(GoogleCredentials credentials) {
        return BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
    }}
```

However, when I run my application, I'm encountering the following error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [vm-dev-393108-80d765f9af09.json] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I've checked the file path multiple times and it appears to be correct. I'm not sure why Spring is unable to locate my JSON file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I am a new Spring Boot developer and this is my first time trying to establish a connection to Google's BigQuery from a Spring Boot application. I am developing my application in Gitpod, an online development environment.

So far, I have tried different ways to define the path to my JSON credentials file:

I initially used the full path, like my-todo/src/main/resources/vm-dev-393108-80d765f9af09.json, but it didn't work.

I then tried copying the relative path from the context menu in my IDE and used that path in my application.properties file, but the application still could not locate the JSON file.

My expectation is that when I run my Spring Boot application, it should be able to use the provided path to locate the JSON file, load the credentials, and connect to BigQuery successfully.

However, regardless of how I define the path to my JSON file, I keep encountering a FileNotFoundException stating that the JSON file does not exist, even though the file does indeed exist in my project.

I'm not sure if there's something specific about Spring, Gitpod, or my relative inexperience that is causing this issue. I suspect there might be some limitations or specificities in Gitpod's workspace that prevent it from accessing a JSON file located within the workspace itself. I am eager to understand the mistake I'm making and learn how to correct it.

Remember, the more context and details you provide, the easier it will be for others to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the Issue with Google BigQuery and Spring Boot Integration

For anyone encountering challenges when integrating Google's BigQuery with a Spring Boot application, here's the solution that worked for me:

Spring Cloud GCP Auto Configuration: I realized that manual BigQuery configuration might not always be necessary. The Spring Cloud GCP library provides an auto-configuration for BigQuery, which can simplify the setup process. Detailed information about this feature can be found here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#google-cloud-bigquery.

Project ID vs. Project Name: A notable point of confusion was distinguishing between the Google Cloud Project ID and Project Name. These terms might seem interchangeable, but they serve different purposes. When you attempt to query a non-existent project, the returned error might be misleading. In my experience, the error hinted at a regional problem, which was not the actual issue.

Proper Permissions: After setting up with the correct project ID, it's essential to ensure your service account has the appropriate permissions. Inadequate permissions will prevent requests to BigQuery, and the error messages might not directly indicate this. It's recommended to verify permissions in the Google Cloud Console.

In summary:

Utilize Spring Cloud GCP's auto-configuration when integrating BigQuery with Spring Boot.
Ensure you are using the correct Project ID and avoid confusing it with the Project Name.
Confirm that your service account possesses the needed permissions for BigQuery operations.
I hope this summary assists other developers who encounter similar challenges.